# $(".selectable").selectable("disable"); grays out

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectable

I am using  the jQuery selectable widget. But when I try to use the disable method `$(".selectable").selectable("disable");` OR `$(".selectable").selectable({disabled:true});`  of that widget, it grays out the whole page. I have tried using `$(".selectable").selectable("destroy");` as well. It didn't work for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="SubOperation">
<ul class="DataTable">
    <p class="SelectAll">Select All</p>         
    <li>Level 0</li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>Level 2</li>
    <li>Level 2</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: That is how I did.
$(".DataTable").selectable("disable");
$(".DataTable").selectable({disabled: true);

and then
$(".DataTable").selectable("destroy");

I am new to stackflow so pls forgive any mistakes

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @villageboy I think you should look at this [selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) link. Also, make sure you are including `jquery-ui`

Comment: I looked at selectable api many times over. and Yes jquery-ui is included.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in CSS by giving `opacity: 1` to the relative `div`

Thanks for all who tried helping.